# Ansible - loop tasks one by one based on list

Tags: ansible

Imagine this playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_host
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    mylist:
      - abc
      - def
      - xyz
  tasks:
    - name: dummy task 1
      shell: "echo 'task 1 {{ item }}'"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
 
    - name: dummy task 2
      shell: "echo 'task 2 {{ item }}'"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Would it be possible to let Ansible loop over the tasks, one by one, based on the items defined in `mylist`?

The desired result would be:

```bash
task 1 abc
task 2 abc

task 1 def
task 2 def

task 1 xyz
task 2 xyz
```

Comment: I currently have a bad workaround, https://pastebin.com/fycdH6nn.
It got the job done. I'm simply searching for a better approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the tasks in a separate file (e.g., `tasks.yaml`) and then loop over an [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html) task.

If we have a file `tasks.yaml` with this content:

```
- name: task1
  debug:
    msg: "task 1 {{ item }}"

- name: task2
  debug:
    msg: "task 2 {{ item }}"
```

And `playbook.yaml` with this content:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: tasks.yaml
      loop:
        - abc
        - def
        - xyz
```

Then running `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml` produces as output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] ***********************************************************
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/tasks.yaml for localhost => (item=abc)
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/tasks.yaml for localhost => (item=def)
included: /home/lars/tmp/ansible/tasks.yaml for localhost => (item=xyz)

TASK [task1] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 1 abc"
}

TASK [task2] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 2 abc"
}

TASK [task1] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 1 def"
}

TASK [task2] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 2 def"
}

TASK [task1] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 1 xyz"
}

TASK [task2] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "task 2 xyz"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Would it be possible somehow/someway to do it in the same file?

Comment: No. Using `include_tasks` (or a related action, like `include_role`) is how you achieve your desired behavior.

Comment: Alright, I guess that's the way to go then. Thanks for your answer.